# Print all elements of an Arraylist of List/String type

Tags: java, android, arraylist, logic

I need to print each element of an `ArrayList`. This `ArrayList` can be of type `ArrayList` or `String`. Further children of this list can also be of type list.

This is what I have written till now:

```
public class Logic extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Object> parent = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Object> check = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        parent.add("list 1");
        check.add("list 2");
        check.add(parent);
        parent.add(check);

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.size(); i++) {
            if (!(parent.get(i) instanceof ArrayList)) {
                Log.e("test",(String) parent.get(i));
            } else {
                printDetails((ArrayList<?>) parent.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void printDetails(ArrayList<?> child) {
        for (int i = 0; i < child.size(); i++) {
            if (!(child.get(i) instanceof ArrayList)) {
                Log.e("test1", (String) child.get(i));
            } else {
                printDetails((ArrayList<?>) child.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this prints all the abrupt values without any expected order. Expectation is that all the values should print serially. Like if the first element of a list is string it should first print the string else if it is a list if should print all values of this child list and if any element of the child list is again list it should print these values too and move back to the next element of parent list.

If this is the input:

```
ArrayList<Object> parent = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Object> child1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Object> subChild1= new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Object> nestedSubChild1= new ArrayList<>();

parent.add("list 1");
parent.add("list 1-2");


child1.add("childlist 2");
subChild1.add("sublist 1-1");
subChild1.add("sublist 1-2");
nestedSubChild1.add("nestedlist 1-1");
nestedSubChild1.add("nestedlist 1-2");
subChild1.add(nestedSubChild1);
child1.add(subChild1);
parent.add(child1);
```

I want this output

> ```
> list 1
> list 1-2
> childlist 2
> sublist 1-1
> sublist 1-2
> nestedlist 1-1
> nestedlist 1-2
> ```

Another requirement is to use recursion so that the code will be efficient.

Comment: You have `check.add(parent)` and then `parent.add(check)`. This creates cyclic referencing. Is this intentional?

Comment: @PrasadKarunagoda this is just for testing purpose. This won't happen in real-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by creating a recursive method for printing out the *lists*

```
public static void printRecursiveList(List myList) {
    for (Object obj : myList) {
        if (obj instanceof List) {
            printRecursiveList((List) obj); // call itself again since its a list
        } else {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call it using :

```
parent.stream().forEach(i -> {
    if (i instanceof List) {
        printRecursiveList((List) i);
    } else {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
});
```

Here we stream over the list `parent` and if the element is an instance of a list we invoke `printRecursiveList(...)` else we print out the element.

Comment: understood wt was wrong with my code. Thanks Nicholas K

Answer (score 0):

You can print required elements of `Model` class by overriding `toString()` method of an Object.

Support You got and `ArrayList` of `Child` Class, i.e. `ArrayList<Child>`:

 - `toString()` can be implemented like:

```
class Child {

    private String name;
    .... some other variable

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: "  + name + ": last updated: " +lastUpdated;
    }
}
```

Now, when you print `child.toString()` It will print the result just like you want to print it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with static variables it compiles as you expected. See below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    static ArrayList<Object> parent = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Object> check = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Object> check2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        parent.add("list 1");
        parent.add("list 2");
        check.add("list 3");
        check2.add("list 4");
        check2.add("list 5");
        check2.add("list 6");
        check.add(check2);
        //check.add(parent);
        parent.add(check);

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(parent.toArray()));
        System.out.println("-------");
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.size(); i++) {
            if (!(parent.get(i) instanceof ArrayList)) {
                System.out.println("firstPart -> " + (String) parent.get(i));
            }
            else {
                printDetails((ArrayList<?>) parent.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    public static void printDetails(ArrayList<?> child) {
        for (int i = 0; i < child.size(); i++) {
            if (!(child.get(i) instanceof ArrayList)) {
                System.out.println("lastPart -> " + (String) child.get(i));
            } else {
                printDetails((ArrayList<?>) child.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i find that when i uncomment the commented block "check.add(parent);", it creates nested loop which generates java.lang.StackOverflowError.

By the way you can use

```
Arrays.deepToString(parent.toArray());
```

method if you only log the values in order.

Comment: Order does't matter.. I just want all the values of parent list to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrintArrayList
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<Object> parent = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Object> child1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Object> subChild1= new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Object> nestedSubChild1= new ArrayList<>();

    parent.add("list 1");
    parent.add("list 1-2");


    child1.add("childlist 2");
    subChild1.add("sublist 1-1");
    subChild1.add("sublist 1-2");
    nestedSubChild1.add("nestedlist 1-1");
    nestedSubChild1.add("nestedlist 1-2");
    subChild1.add(nestedSubChild1);
    child1.add(subChild1);
    parent.add(child1);

    print(parent);
  }

  public static void print(ArrayList<Object> arrayList)
  {
    for (Object element : arrayList)
    {
      if (element instanceof ArrayList)
      {
        print((ArrayList) element);
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println(element);
      }
    }
  }
}
```